# How to query if the day of the start date > the day of the end date?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, date

I use LocaleDate.now in Android to get data from Sqlite based on the start date of week and the end date of the week. For example, if start date is 20/07/2020, then the end date will be 26/07/2020. I will get data from range date betwwen 20/07/2020 and 26/07/2020. My code run fine until today, i get start date of this week is 27/07/2020, the end date is 02/08/2020. I surprised because i couldn't get the data from sql, so i debugged and i realized the Sqlite couldn't get the data from range date between 27/07/2020 and 02/08/2020. I think if the day of start date(27) > the day of the end date(2) then Sqlite can't query it. How to solve this problem?

```
SELECT name 
FROM date_detail  
where date BETWEEN '27/07/2020' and  '02/08/2020'
//not show me anything
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can solve this problem by saving dates into database in another format, such as 'yyyy-mm-dd' or with timestamp, so it can select dates between two dates.

Comment: Change format to yyyy-mm-dd solve my problem. Thanks